# access scalar in dataframe in each iterate loop

Tags: pandas, numpy, ta-lib

I have a dataframe of a cryptoCoin in the format of:

```
       time           open     high     low      close    volume      TM
0      1618617600000  61342.7  61730.9  61268.7  61648.8  82.523952   5
1      1618618500000  61648.9  61695.3  61188.4  61333.2  72.375605   5
2      1618619400000  61333.1  61396.4  61144.2  61200.0  52.882392   5
3      1618620300000  61200.0  61509.4  61199.9  61446.2  48.429485   5
4      1618621200000  61446.2  61764.7  61446.2  61647.4  83.822974   5
...              ...      ...      ...      ...      ...        ...  ..
19213  1635909300000  63006.2  63087.2  62935.0  63081.9  35.265568  26
19214  1635910200000  63081.9  63214.5  62950.1  63084.0  41.213263  30
19215  1635911100000  63084.0  63236.0  63027.6  63213.9  32.429295  21
19216  1635912000000  63213.8  63213.8  63021.5  63024.1  47.032509  19
19217  1635912900000  63024.1  63091.4  62852.1  62970.7  84.098123  16
```

I want to calculate moving average of the close price with varied timeperiod, the timeperiod came from a TM column. I will use talib/ta library. efficiency is necessary so I tried apply and np.where:

```
dataframe['DMA'] = dataframe.apply(lambda x: ta.MA(dataframe['close'], timeperiod=dataframe['TM']), axis=0)
```

and

```
dataframe['DMA'] = np.where(dataframe['TM'].values , ta.MA(dataframe['close'], timeperiod=dataframe['TM'].values), )
```

both return error:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

which I believed came from `timeperiod= dataframe['TM'].values` part. and if I use `dataframe['TM'].values[0]`, only the first value, which is 5, apply to all iterate loop. How can I access to the scalar of the cell in TM, in vectorized-way and not iterating over index or use for_loop.

My desire output:
output dataframe has another column at the end, named it DMA, and last 3 rows should be like

```
............... DMA

    19215 ..... ta.MA(dataframe['close'], timeperiod = 21)
    19216 ..... ta.MA(dataframe['close'], timeperiod = 19)
    19217 ..... ta.MA(dataframe['close'], timeperiod = 16)
```

- in index 19215 I want to calculate Moving Average of last 21 close
  prices
- in index 19216 I want to calculate Moving Average of last 19
  close prices
- in index 19216 I want to calculate Moving Average of
  last 16 close prices

Appreciate your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "varied timeperiod"? A timeperiod shouldn't be fix like MA10, MA100, etc?

Comment: I want Dynamic timeperiod, in high volatility market, shorter timerange and in range market longer timerange. for example: 10 candles vs 45 candles

Comment: Can you give an input sample and it expected output, please (just for close column)?

Comment: I added the desire output at the end of the above post